# Is it possible to use one generic/abstract service in ServiceStack?

Tags: api, rest, servicestack

I am developing a (hopefully) RESTful API using ServiceStack.

I noticed that most of my services look the same, for example, a GET method will look **something** like this:

```
        try
        {
            Validate();
            GetData(); 
            return Response();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //TODO: Log the exception
            throw; //rethrow
        }
```

lets say I got 20 resources, 20 request DTOs, so I got about 20 services of the same template more or less...

I tried to make a generic or abstract Service so I can create inheriting services which just implement the relevant behavior but I got stuck because the request DTOs weren't as needed for serialization.

**Is there any way to do it?**

**EDIT:**

an Example for what I'm trying to do:

```
public abstract class MyService<TResponse,TRequest> : Service
{
    protected abstract TResponse InnerGet();
    protected abstract void InnerDelete();
    public TResponse Get(TRequest request)
    {
        //General Code Here.
        TResponse response = InnerGet();
        //General Code Here.
        return response;
    }

    public void Delete(TRequest request)
    {
        //General Code Here.
        InnerDelete();
        //General Code Here.
    }
}

public class AccountService : MyService<Accounts, Account>
{

    protected override Accounts InnerGet()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();//Get the data from BL
    }

    protected override void InnerDelete()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this in the [New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) we've introduced the concept of a IServiceRunner that decouples the execution of your service from the implementation of it.

To add your own Service Hooks you just need to override the default Service Runner in your AppHost from its default implementation:

```
public virtual IServiceRunner<TRequest> CreateServiceRunner<TRequest>(ActionContext actionContext)
{           
    return new ServiceRunner<TRequest>(this, actionContext); //Cached per Service Action
}
```

With your own:

```
public override IServiceRunner<TRequest> CreateServiceRunner<TRequest>(ActionContext actionContext)
{           
    return new MyServiceRunner<TRequest>(this, actionContext); //Cached per Service Action
}
```

Where MyServiceRunner is just a custom class implementing the custom hooks you're interested in, e.g:

```
public class MyServiceRunner<T> : ServiceRunner<T> {
    public override void OnBeforeExecute(IRequestContext requestContext, TRequest request) {
      // Called just before any Action is executed
    }

    public override object OnAfterExecute(IRequestContext requestContext, object response) {
      // Called just after any Action is executed, you can modify the response returned here as well
    }

    public override object HandleException(IRequestContext requestContext, TRequest request, Exception ex) {
      // Called whenever an exception is thrown in your Services Action
    }
}
```

Also for more fine-grained Error Handling options check out the [Error Handling wiki page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling).

Comment: I'm not sure how I can leverage this to what I meant... I used it to log exceptions in one place, but here I want to create sort of a template service so that I don't need to create multiple service classes

Comment: or I can inherit this service, which will have Get, Post, etc methods already implemented, and in those services classes I'll only need to implement getting the data and crating it etc..

Comment: See the https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling page for how to generically handle all exceptions. The Old API (i.e. ServiceBase<T>) lets you inherit, but we've decoupled that in the New API using the IServiceRunner hooks above.

Comment: I've edited my question with an example of what I want to do (more or less). can this be done using hooks or some other way?

Comment: are my intentions clearer now? is my goal in the edit possible?

Comment: No, you can't abstract away the entry points of your service into a generic base class. Register a custom `ServiceRunner<T>` like I've described above if you want add your own custom hooks. Otherwise add custom logic using a Request/Response filter and see the [Error Handling wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling) with how to generically handle errors. The [Order of Operations wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations) shows all the custom hooks available.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add an additional layer where I can handle Logic per entity:

Base Logic Sample:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    long Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IReadOnlyLogic<Entity> where Entity : class, IEntity
{
    List<Entity> GetAll();
    Entity GetById(long Id);
}
public abstract class ReadOnlyLogic<Entity> : IReadOnlyLogic<Entity> where Entity : class, IEntity, new()
{
    public IDbConnection Db { get; set; }

    #region HOOKS
    protected SqlExpression<Entity> OnGetList(SqlExpression<Entity> query) { return query; }
    protected SqlExpression<Entity> OnGetSingle(SqlExpression<Entity> query) { return OnGetList(query); }
    #endregion

    public List<Entity> GetAll()
    {
        var query = OnGetList(Db.From<Entity>());
        return Db.Select(query);
    }

    public Entity GetById(long id)
    {
        var query = OnGetSingle(Db.From<Entity>())
                .Where(e => e.Id == id);

        var entity = Db.Single(query);

        return entity;
    }
}
```

Then we can use hooks like:

```
public interface IHello : IReadOnlyLogic<Hello> { }

public class HelloLogic : ReadOnlyLogic<Hello>, IHello
{
    protected override SqlExpression<Hello> OnGetList(SqlExpression<Hello> query)
    {
        return query.Where(h => h.Name == "Something");
    }
}
```

Finally our service only calls our logic:

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
    IHello helloLogic;

    public object Get()
    {
        return helloLogic.GetAll();
    }
}
```